# What is the proper URI scheme for RESTful creation of a tree of nodes?

Tags: rest, tree

I have a `ProductInstance`, which has zero or more parents, also `ProductInstances`. They are a tree. For example:

```
- ProductInstance VM
  - ProductInstance RAID
    - ProductInstance DISK
  - ProductInstance CPU
```

I'd like my URI-scheme to create these, to be clean and RESTful. How should I set this up?

One scheme I came up with, is to nest the URI resources:

- `GET  http://example.com/product_instances/new` - HTML form
- `POST http://example.com/product_instances` - Create a new resource
- `GET http://example.com/product_instances/1/children/new` - HTML form
- `POST http://example.com/product_instances/1/children` - Create new resource who's parent is product_instance 1.

The other scheme I thought of, is to provide params and re-use the "ordinary new and create":

- `GET  http://example.com/product_instances/new` - HTML form
- `POST http://example.com/product_instances` - Create a new resource
- `GET http://example.com/product_instances/new?parent=1` - HTML form
- `POST http://example.com/product_instances/` - include parent=1 in payload.

Are there any standards for this pattern? Is there some rule or guideline that explains how to deal with tree-ed items in RESTful URI schemes?

Note: I focus on the new and create only, because I would say that the `show, update/edit and delete` are no different for items with and without parents, since they act on an already stored `ProductInstance` and therefore the parent is known and needs not to be provided in the URI or payload.